# How to union 2 columns with different data type in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

How to union 2 columns with different data type in SAS?

Comment: Does SAS have something like CONVERT or CAST ? so you can cast one of the columns so that it matches the other ?

Comment: What do you mean by "union 2 columns"? Writing one below the other? If so, see proc append with `FORCE` option.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  You can use PUT() function to convert a number to a string. There are many defined formats or you can  create you own format to control what text is generated.  You can use INPUT() function to convert strings into values. Use a numeric INFORMAT to create a numeric value.  Again you can define your own informats to control what number the text is converted into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS uses formats to control the display of values as text.  It uses informats to control the conversion of text into values.  You can use the PUT(), or PUTC or PUTN, function to convert values (either numbers or string) into strings. You can use the INPUT(), or INPUTC or INPUTN, function to convert strings into values (either numbers or strings).

Answer (score 0):

If you are try to stack data with `UNION` and the source columns are of different types, one (or more) of the source columns need to be converted to the type of the target column type.

Example:

```
data have_num;
  do x = 1 to 10;
    output;
  end;

data have_char;
  do _n_ = 20 to 30;
    x = put (_n_, 8.-L);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  %* use input() to convert;
  create table want_x_num as
  select x from have_num
  union
  select input(x,best12.) as x from have_char
  ;

  * use cats() to convert;
  create table want_x_char as
  select cats(x) from have_num
  union
  select x from have_char
  ;
```